# Where the powrmart.dtd file will be located in Informatica Powercenter client?

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

All the XMLs generated from Informatica PowerCenter Client(Repository manager,Workflow manager,Designer ). These validated against the powrmart.dtd

I just want to know the location of powrmart.dtd

Comment: You could use the Windows search function inside the installation folder to find the file!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest version is version 8.0, and can be found in the following location (on your Windows machine) after installation of the Informatica Cloud Secure Agent:

```
C:\Program Files\Informatica Cloud Secure Agent\main\bin\rdtm\powrmart.dtd
```

It can also be found online at the following location:
https://code.google.com/p/rishav/source/browse/powrmart.dtd?r=79b8fc2157bbdfac9283679975d84d931691a4aa

Answer (score 0):

You could disable searching of the file by adding below line while parsing the XML.

DocumentBuilderFactory factory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
*factory.setFeature("http://apache.org/xml/features/nonvalidating/load-external-dtd", false);*